# Removing rows containing NA in every column

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl, bioinformatics

I have a tab delimited file which looks like this:

```
gene    v1  v2  v3  v4
g1  NA  NA  NA  NA
g2  NA  NA  2   3
g3  NA  NA  NA  NA
g4  1   2   3   2
```

The number of fields in every line is fixed and same.
I want to remove those rows from the above file where all the fields for every row from column 2 through last is NA. Then the output should look like:

```
gene    v1  v2  v3  v4
g2  NA  NA  2   3
g4  1   2   3   2
```

Comment: If the non-NA fields are always nonnegative integers, a regular expression as simple as `\s\d` differentiates between the “good” and the “bad” lines.

Comment: if you're doing bioinformatics work why not just use R

Comment: Because I am using command line tools upstream to generate this file and I will prefer awk or perl solution if I don't have to save the file to open in R. Of course in R you can remove this with `is.na`  check if I think

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!="NA"){ print; break } }' file
```

Loop through the fields starting at the second field and print the line if a field not containing `NA` is found. Then break the loop.

Answer (score 10):

Using GNU sed

```
sed -e '/g[0-9]\+\(\s*NA\s*\)\+$/d' filename
```

Short explanation:

`g[0-9]\+\(\s*NA\s*\)\+$` is a regex matching `g` followed by at least one digit, then any number of `NA`s with optional spaces between until the end of the line.

`sed -e '/<regex>/d'` deletes all lines that match `<regex>`

A more standard regexp with the same meaning would be:

```
sed -Ee '/g[0-9]+([[:space:]]*NA[[:space:]]*)+$/d' filename
```

Comment: Please note that `\+` and `\s` are non-standard regular expressions and will match a simple `+` or `s` in most `sed` versions. Use `\{1,\}` instead of `\+` and `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` to have portable code.

Answer (score 9):

With `all` from the Perl List::Util module:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=all -alne 'shift @F; print unless all { $_ eq "NA" } @F' file
gene  v1  v2  v3  v4
g2    NA  NA  2   3
g4    1   2   3   2
```

Answer (score 9):

With `grep`:

```
egrep -v -x 'g[0-9]+([[:blank:]]+NA)*[[:blank:]]*' filename
```

This causes grep to **not** display (`-v`) lines where the entire line (`-x`) matches:

- lower case g in first column, followed by one or more digits
- any number of instances of whitespace followed by NA
- optional trailing whitespace

Comment: +1, but note also that the number of fields is fixed, so you could use `{4}` instead of `*` after the `NA` group, and you may want to change the first `[[:blank:]]*` to `[[:blank:]]+` to make the whitespace separators mandatory. Regardless, I have never understood why everyone insists on pulling out the `awk` bazooka to solve these simple filtering problems that `grep` handles easily.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @Kevin.  I incorporated your first suggestion, but I am retaining the other `*` so that this solution works equally well for any arbitrary number of `NA` columns, so long as they are **all** NA.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
$ grep -P '\t(?!NA(\t|$))' file

$ sed -e 'h;s/\tNA//g;/\t/!d;g' file

$ perl -MList::MoreUtils=any -F'\t' -lane 'print if any { ! /^NA$/ } @F[1..$#F]' file
```